# How to insert part of hyperlink into infopath field

Tags: infopath

I need to insert a part of link into an InfoPath field to get it in the SharePoint column.

E.g.

> http:\mySPsite\ifopath.aspx&IM1234

`IM1234` should be in the field.

Is it possible ? How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you should be able to do this with a function, substring-after might do what you want to. Do you need to strip the link that is added to the field in the form?

```
 substring-after(fieldThatContainsTheLink, "&")
```

Comment: I think I wasn't clear enough in the request sorry. I would like to display a part of the URL of the infoPath form. So it's not yet placed in the form. Is there a way to make a link ?

Comment: I'm afraid i don't understand what you are trying to achieve. Can you add some more details or an example?

Comment: so I have a sharepoint list with cutom form in infopath. when i click new item, infopath form appears to be filled by user. I would like to add an extention to this form so the information from the url. so if I send to user URL http://myspsite/infopathform&IM1234 I need even complete link is integrated in the form.

Answer (score 0):

I found out solution for this this problem in this link:

https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/infopath/2010/06/03/how-to-pass-querystring-data-into-an-infopath-form/